# Stuff isn't appending to my list

Tags: python, queue

I'm trying to create a simulation where there are two printers and I find the average wait time for each.  I'm using a class for the printer and task in my program.  Basically, I'm adding the wait time to each of each simulation to a list and calculating the average time.  My issue is that I'm getting a division by 0 error so nothing is being appended.  When I try it with 1 printer (Which is the same thing essentially) I have no issues.  Here is the code I have for the second printer.  I'm using a queue for this.

```
if printers == 2:
    for currentSecond in range(numSeconds):
        if newPrintTask():
            task = Task(currentSecond,minSize,maxSize)
            printQueue.enqueue(task)

        if (not labPrinter1.busy()) and (not labPrinter2.busy()) and \
           (not printQueue.is_empty()):
            nexttask = printQueue.dequeue()
            waitingtimes.append(nexttask.waitTime(currentSecond))
            labPrinter1.startNext(nexttask)

        elif (not labPrinter1.busy()) and (labPrinter2.busy()) and \
             (not printQueue.is_empty()):
            nexttask = printQueue.dequeue()
            waitingtimes.append(nexttask.waitTime(currentSecond))
            labPrinter1.startNext(nexttask)

        elif (not labPrinter2.busy()) and (labPrinter1.busy()) and \
             (not printQueue.is_empty()):
            nexttask = printQueue.dequeue()
            waitingtimes.append(nexttask.waitTime(currentSecond))
            labPrinter2.startNext(nexttask)

        labPrinter1.tick()
        labPrinter2.tick()


        averageWait = sum(waitingtimes)/len(waitingtimes)
        outfile.write("Average Wait %6.2f secs %3d tasks remaining." \
              %(averageWait,printQueue.size()))
```

Any assistance would be great!

Edit:  I should mention that this happens no matter the values.  I could have a page range of 99-100 and a PPM of 1 yet I still get divided by 0.

Comment: _I'm getting a division by 0_ . These are often due to using `int` instead of `float`. Is that something you checked for? Also, are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @patrick I've set everything to be an integer in my main method.  I'm using 3

Comment: What is the variable `waitingtimes`? Is it a list, a queue, a class you built?

Comment: Waitingtimes is the list, it was defined above this

Comment: You can combine your `if` and first `elif` if you want. If `labPrinter1` is not busy, you don't care about `labPrinter2`, so just leave it out of the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem stems from an empty `waitingtimes` on the first iteration or so. If there is no print job in the queue, and there has never been a waiting time inserted, you are going to reach the bottom of the loop with `waitingtimes==[]` (empty), and then do:

```
sum(waitingtimes) / len(waitingtimes)
```

Which will be

```
sum([])  / len([])
```

Which is

```
0 / 0
```

The easiest way to deal with this would just be to check for it, or catch it:

```
if not waitingtimes:
    averageWait = 0
else:
    averageWait = sum(waitingtimes)/len(waitingtimes)
```

Or:

```
try:
    averageWait = sum(waitingtimes)/len(waitingtimes)

except ZeroDivisionError:
    averageWait = 0
```

Comment: cool! couldn't you do this nicely with `while`? Or would that be impossible / a bad idea here?

Comment: Do what with `while`? The original statement is inside a `for` loop, which I think is all the OP needs.

Comment: check for len() being zero

Comment: I'll say, "no." At the bottom of the loop, the `len` of the list is what it is - there are no changes being made to it. So there's no need to loop waiting for it to change. Instead, just let the for loop finish, go back to the top, and eventually some print job will show up and the list will grow to len=1.

Comment: It's not just for this though, it's for everything.  Even if I have the PPM at 1, it still goes to 0.

Comment: Austin, I see it now, it was just a plain misunderstanding on my part. Thanks for your explanations!